# SwiftUI: Pass string to view on button press

Tags: string, view, swiftui

I want to pass a string on a button press in SwiftUI from ContentView to SoundPageView.
Each different button should pass a different string. It is an English language learning app so I want to pass a grammar category.

For example.

```
                NavigationLink(destination: SoundPageView()) {
                    Text("Should")
                }
                .buttonStyle(GrammarButton())
                NavigationLink(destination: SoundPageView()) {
                    Text("Articles)
                }
                .buttonStyle(GrammarButton())
                NavigationLink(destination: SoundPageView()) {
                    Text("First Conditional")
                }
                .buttonStyle(GrammarButton())
```

My SoundPageView is a view that has a lot of buttons that play sounds.

```
struct SoundPageView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                HStack(spacing:0) {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            playSound(sound: "art_audio1", type: "mp3")
                        }) {
                            Text("Button 1")
                        }
```

I want to pass a category string like "should" "art" or "first" to SoundPageView so that different sounds are loaded for the buttons.

I also want to use the category string to alter the audio filenames but I'm not sure how to do that. Something like...

playSound(sound: \category + "_audio1", type: "mp3")

I am new to SwiftUI and a beginner coder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be like the following

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: SoundPageView(category: "should")) {
    Text("Should")
}
.buttonStyle(GrammarButton())
NavigationLink(destination: SoundPageView(category: "art")) {
    Text("Articles)
}
.buttonStyle(GrammarButton())
NavigationLink(destination: SoundPageView(category: "first")) {
    Text("First Conditional")
}
.buttonStyle(GrammarButton())
```

and

```
struct SoundPageView: View {
    var category: String

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                HStack(spacing:0) {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio1", type: "mp3")
                        }) {
                            Text("Button 1")
                        }
```

Comment: I have an error message in SoundPageView_Previews :Missing argument for parameter 'category' in call

Comment: Well, you did not show Preview. Of course now `category` is required parameter for `SoundPageView`, so you have to provide some in Preview as well, like in links, any. Like `SoundPageView(category: "art")`